# Ruby script return array to powershell

Tags: ruby, powershell

I have a Ruby script and I am calling this ruby script from a
Powershell script. I want Ruby to return the result as an array back to
Powershell..So i will be able to use the array in Powershell. I am a
very beginner in Ruby, so need help on constructing the array in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

The vast majority of Ruby implementations are built on the Unix model: every input and output is an (unstructured) character stream. So, you will have to have additional PowerShell code to parse that unstructured character stream into a PowerShell array. This can ben made easier if you emit some well-known format as your character stream such as JSON, YAML, XML, XAML, CSV.

Alernatively, you could try an approach with IronRuby, and write a PowerShell cmdlet in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

You left out what your Ruby array should contain, so I would recommend to look at the examples in the [Ruby documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html), like

```
first_array = ["Matz", "Guido"]
```

on how to create and populate a Ruby array.

The second step is how you transfer the contents of this array into the outer / calling Powershell script. One way is using the standard output stream, thus the Ruby script writes the contents of the array to standard output, 
and the Powershell script catches it as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534500/powershell-script-1-calls-script-2-how-to-return-value-from-script-2-to-scri).

Example for the Ruby side (when you entered the example line above):

```
puts first_array
```

will result in such output

```
Matz
Guido
```

with an entry on each line, or if your prefer CSV, you might try

```
puts first_array.join(',')
```

which will result in this output

```
Matz,Guido
```

Or you use JSON or whatever is best fit, when you parse that ouput later.

The final step would be to parse that output string within the Powershell to its array format.